# create user with custom shell using VBSCRIPT

Tags: shell, windows-7, vbscript

im using this script to create a user... i would like it to set the shell to something like "c:\app\myapp.exe" and only for that user.. hope someone can fill in the blanks for me. thank you.. for windows 7

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then

Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
ObjShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
WScript.ScriptFullName & """" &_
 " RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1

else

strComputer = "PC2"
Set colAccounts = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "")
Set objUser = colAccounts.Create("user", "Admin2")
objUser.SetPassword "test"
objUser.SetInfo
msgbox "done"

end if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838576%28v=winembedded.5%29.aspx) correctly, you need to set this:

```
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\IniFileMapping\system.ini\boot]
"Shell"="USR:Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"
```

and then specify the user-specific shell in the `Shell` value in `Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon` in the user's registry hive (stored in the `ntuser.dat` in the user's profile, which you need to [load into the registry](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732157.aspx) to be able to modify it). If you want to do that with VBScript, you have to use something like this:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run "reg load HKU\temp C:\Users\username\ntuser.dat", 0, True
```

Unload the hive after you're finished:

```
sh.Run "reg unload HKU\temp", 0, True
```